# How to use filter after using hide on tr

Tags: tablesorter

I currently use tablesorter on a legacy project to add filtering and i'm stuck with a behaviour:
if you manually use `$("#tbody>tr").hide()`, then `$("#tbody>tr.someClass").show()`,
Filtering seems not work ( I think tablesorter lost his reference of tr... but i can't find how to told it to update his internal ref).

here an exemple of this behaviour : 
https://jsfiddle.net/f2qdz3dp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a custom theme, you'll need to add this bit of css:

```
.filtered {
  display: none;
}
```

You can rename the css class by modifying the [`filter_filteredRow` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-filteredrow).

Also, you can set an initial search value by including a `data-value` attribute on the header cell:

```
<td class="info" ... data-value="bla">info</td>
```

This attribute name can also be changed using the [`filter_defaultAttrib` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-defaultattrib).

Comment: Thank Mottie,
my error is not due to a custom theme, but you point me where is my problem.
my problem is due to the version of jquery i'm stuck with... 1.9...
in this version, `.show()` add an inline style `display:table-row` for tr.
I corrrect this with this solution :
https://jsfiddle.net/tgg9eh1u/
Thanks again for your work Mottie.